# Check a checkbox by clicking the parent container?

Tags: jquery

Instead of having to click the little specific checkbox area, id like to check the checkbox by clicking the parent container, here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVjCr/). Instead of adding the color red, id like to check the box within the `li`.

I tried looking for this answer but couldnt find what I was looking for, this should be quite simple, might be fun for some.

**HTML:**

```
<li class="option table selected">
<div class="cell" id="left">
    <div class="fontawesome-menu"></div>
</div>
<div class="cell" id="center">
    <div class="option-text">I like green eggs</div>
</div>
<div class="cell" id="right">
    <div class="option-checkbox">
        <div class="check"></div>
        <input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="hidden" value="0">
        <input id="personalization_result_memory_0" name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="checkbox" value="1">
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('seuss');
});
```

Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVjCr/) for a better understanding of my question.

Comment: That's what `<label>`s are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

[Original](http://jsfiddle.net/CVjCr/2/) without changing to [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)s:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var el = $(this).toggleClass('seuss');
    el.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', el.hasClass('seuess'));
});
```

[Updated using `<label>`s](http://jsfiddle.net/CVjCr/3/):

HTML:

```
<li class="option table selected">
    <label for="personalization_result_memory_0">
        <div class="cell" id="left">
            <div class="fontawesome-menu"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell" id="center">
            <div class="option-text">I like green eggs</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell" id="right">
            <div class="option-checkbox">
                <div class="check"></div>
                <input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="hidden" value="0">
                <input id="personalization_result_memory_0" name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="checkbox" value="1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var el = $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('seuss');
});
```

Note, even when you wrap the input in the `<label>`, you should use the `for` attribute.

Comment: Hey buddy, you helped me out a few days ago thanks for another helpful answer, let me implement this. Nice, I havent used `.prop` often, I see it alot, but I dont know when to use it, I see how it ties in well with this function..

Comment: What about unchecking as well? Let me see what I can come up with.. first :p

Comment: Updated, assuming that you'd want to remove the class when you uncheck.

Comment: yeah looks good, if I were to use a label, wouldnt I need to wrap the whole `<li>` block with the label

Comment: Yep, and you could change your JS to look like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVjCr/3/) (I updated the HTML as well)

Comment: Wonderful, this made my day, thanks! I wish I could come up with it myself, but I am still a noob, ill be there soon enough, this really helps me out alot.

Comment: My pleasure. I updated my answer with the new markup and some additional information (mainly that you should always use the `for` attribute because there are some discrepancies between screenreaders)

Comment: Oh okay, definitely a good practice considering there is a vast variety of screen readers. I think it also organizes the blocks a little more nicely.

Comment: why not using click() method  `$(li:has(input[type=checkbox])').click(function (event) {
        if(event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').click();
        }
    });`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<label>` tag

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CVjCr/1/

Added `$(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: yeah but Its a list and i would like to click on the top level li element. By adding a label inside the `li` the li wouldnt be clickable would it..

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, this worked good I just needed to check and uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

It is to easy to use "for" and "id" to implement this feature.
Here is the example.

```html
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="contractConsent" />
<label for="contractConsent">By checking this box, I agree to the terms and conditions. </label>
</div>
```